# IIS: Changed port does work on the Server but not on the Client

Tags: iis

I'd like to create a second Website via IIS, to create 2 Instances of the same application with different settings.

To do so, I copy the whole folder, update the Configs and create a new Website, which is looking on the new Folder. So far so fine,
Now I change the SSL-Binding (I only have this one) from the Port 443 to 444, which is not used (checked it via Netstat-Command).

If I am on the Server itself, I can connect to the Website now by using `https://localhost:444/...`

But as soon as I try it from a Client using `https://something.com:444/...`, I always get the Error the Page can't be displayed.

I get no error in the Eventview, so am I just to dumb to get the correct URL, or do I have to check something else to make a different Port work?

Thanks in advance and a good start in the week

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked your firewall settings?

[Firewall Server 2012 http://www.scriptinghost.de/data/fw.jpg](http://www.scriptinghost.de/data/fw.jpg)

Comment: Ah yes sir, had to create a Port-Rule for this Ports. Thanks alot